# unable to call the code behind of button click after java script function is called

Tags: asp.net

i have a form it has to be validated before code behind of button fires

```
< asp: button id="btn1" runat="server" usesubmittbehaviour="false" onclientclick="validate(this) return"/>
```

and there is click event in code behind, but when the validate returns true click event of button not firing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
validate(this) return
```

with

```
return validate(this)
```

in the onclientclick attribute

Comment: OnClientClick="if (!validate(this)) return;" i did this way..but not working

Comment: @Gani, what you have typed above is actually the correct answer. The actual rendered script will be something like this `onclick="if(!validate(this)) return;__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$btn1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"` which is what you want.

Comment: @MARC with useSubmitBehavior="false"  when any validation is false then a alert popup's and when i click OK on popup the page is automatically refreshing ,i dont want this to happen .How can i do this ??